# Search button google map is not working on my vf page

Tags: visualforce, google-map

`i am newbie in sales force .I am  integrating  Google map  and there is a field  city . along with  search button.  Google map is showing but search  button is not working ..

**I just want to perform it on either html button or apex button**

Any help would be appreciate :)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jsv=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var map;
 function initializeField() {
 var input = document.getElementById('page:frm:field');           
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input); 
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom:6,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,


 center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.593684,78.962880)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('MyMap'),mapOptions);
  new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
   map: map
  });

}
 <button class="btn customBtn pull-right"value="Search"onclick="map_selected = true; initialize(); return false;"></button>
```

Comment: You should share some of your code

Comment: @sfdcDeveloper - If I was to ask you the exact same question, do you feel the question has enough information for you to be able to answer it?

Comment: @mast0r i edit  my question sir ..

Comment: I do not see a method signature for `initialize` so that could be your problem